# Spring ignoring beans on submodule integration tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, integration-testing

I'm working with Spring Boot in a multi-module project. Given that I want to test every module isolated I've created a lot of unit tests and now I'm writing the integration tests for my service project.

That said, I've created an abstract configuration as follows:

```java
package br.com.rk.services;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.Sql;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

/**
 * @author Rhuan Karlus
 * @since 6/3/19
 */
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@Sql({"/drop_data.sql", "/data.sql"})
@SpringBootTest(
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK,
        properties = {
                "spring.datasource.name=HikariCP-Pool",
                "spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource",
                "spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver",
                "spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:.",
                "spring.datasource.username=sa",
                "spring.datasource.password=",
                "spring.flyway.enabled=true",
                "spring.flyway.locations=classpath:/db/migrations/hsql",
                "spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true",
                "spring.jpa.show-sql=true",
                "debug=true"
        })
public abstract class AbstractServiceIntegrationTest {

    @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "br.com.rk")
    static class TestApplication {
    }

}
```

Note that all of my properties are described into the `properties` parameter of the `@SpringBootTest` annotation. This was made as a workaround to avoid creating another `application-test.properties` as it was already created at the `api` module (another module inside the project, it is above the service layer, so for the service layer it didn't even exists).

And here is a simple test:

```java
package br.com.rk.services;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

/**
 * @author Rhuan Karlus
 * @since 6/3/19
 */
public class TestandoIntegracao extends AbstractServiceIntegrationTest {

    @Test
    public void simpleTest() {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }

}
```

The problem happens when I try to run the `simpleTest` method. It loads the context configuration correctly except for the beans and then throws the following message:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'br.com.rk.repositories.audit.AuditRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1509)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724)
    ... 84 more
```

As you can see, the log metions the `AuditRepository` saying that there is no qualifying bean to autowire over one of my services, but the point is that the bean is defined and is annotated with `@Repository` and this works for the `api` module (already mentioned) properly. So I don't understand what's goind on here and I can't figure out how to configure those tests to properly load the Spring Context in order to access all beans.

Just to write it down, here's my `AuditRepository`:

```java
package br.com.rk.repositories.audit;

import br.com.rk.entities.audit.Audit;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

/**
 * @author Rhuan Karlus
 * @since 3/22/19
 */
@Repository
public interface AuditRepository extends JpaRepository<Audit, Long> {

}
```

----------------------------- EDIT -----------------------------

If you guys want to check the complete project, please take a look at https://github.com/rhuankarlus/spring-boot-rest-api/tree/feature/%2315

I'm trying to test the `project-services` module.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not super-experienced with setting up a SpringBoot application from scratch.  However, I have never used `package-private` in a test class as the SpringBoot application class.  I've always used `public`.  Try:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "br.com.rk")
public class MyAwesomeApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyAwesomeApplication .class, args);
    }
}
```

This should be in the `src/main/java` directory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it doesn't work too, I tried to separate this file in the test context and onto the application itself context, both failed.

Comment: Then it might be a classpath issue. I get these from time-to-time.   Are you using an IDE to run the tests, or are you using Maven or Gradle?  I recommend trying an outside runner to rule out an IDE issue.  I find Intellij very flaky with the "Mark directory as..." function.  Are your sources root and test root directories marked as such?  Eclipse is a little better as long as the "Build Path" is correct.  If I'm throwing too much at you, I'll break this down in a separate answer.

Comment: Man, I want to accept your answer because I solved the problem and you were the most close to the answer. So, if you edit it I will accept! Here comes the solution. I'll separate the answer in some comments.

Comment: 1st: I created a class like you said and it didn't work because I've created it inside the package br.com.rk.services scanning "br.com.rk", that's why it couldn't scan my beans, because I don't know why Spring can't scan beans from a package right before the @SpringBootApplication class. So I just passed the class to the package "br.com.rk" and it loads all of my beans correctly.

Comment: 2nd: I moved the class to the test module (src/main/tests) because it didn't need to be inside src/main/java to execute and load context (but I keep the package mentioned before)

Comment: 3rd: I made the @SpringBootApplication class inherit CommandLineRunner because this way it didn't run my embbeded tomcat server (it isn't necessary because I want to test just the service layer) and it works fine. You can check the whole modified code here: https://github.com/rhuankarlus/spring-boot-rest-api/issues/15 and if you change your answer (I hope you change to clarify for any user with the same doubt) I would be glad to accept it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "br.com.rk.*")
```

try

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "br.com.rk")
```

Comment: It didn't work. BTW I removed this configuration (it was only "br.com.rk", I copied/paste the code I've changed to test)